# how can I fix my SQL for loop so that the index is not out of bounds?

Tags: algorithms, loops

I want to create a table that has the following results:

```
id  | field1 | field2
1   |   1    |   1
2   |   2    |   2
3   |   3    |   3
4   |   4    |   4
5   |   1    |   2
6   |   2    |   3
7   |   3    |   4
8   |   4    |   1
9   |   1    |   3
10  |   2    |   4
11  |   3    |   1
12  |   4    |   2
13  |   1    |   4
14  |   2    |   1
15  |   3    |   2
16  |   4    |   3
```

so basically it contains all possible pairs of numbers from 1 to 4. This is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE
  i2 NUMBER := 1;
BEGIN
    
FOR v_LoopCounter IN 1..3 LOOP
    FOR w_LoopCounter IN 0..3 LOOP
        
        INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, FIELD1, FIELD2) 
            VALUES (TO_CHAR(i2),TO_CHAR(w_LoopCounter+1),TO_CHAR(w_LoopCounter+v_LoopCounter));
           i2 := i2 + 1;
           
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;
COMMIT;
END;
```

but it produces wrong results, the field2 is out of range in further cases:

```
id  | field1 | field2
1   |   1    |   1
2   |   2    |   2
3   |   3    |   3
4   |   4    |   4
5   |   1    |   2
6   |   2    |   3
7   |   3    |   4
8   |   4    |   5  <-- here is a bad value
9   |   1    |   3
10  |   2    |   4
11  |   3    |   5  <-- here is a bad value
12  |   4    |   6  <-- here is a bad value, etc.
13  |   1    |   4
14  |   2    |   5
15  |   3    |   6
16  |   4    |   7
```

how can I adjust my code so that it focuses only a specific range and loops through it?

Thanks!

Comment: good catch, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the order of the values is not important, you could simply do:

```
id = 1
for i = 1 to 4 do
    for j = 1 to 4 do
        INSERT(id, i, j)
        id += 1
```

If you want the exact same order as stated in your question, I think this is a solution:

```
id = 1
for i = 1 to 4 do
    for j = 1 to 4 do
        k = (i + j - 2) mod 4 + 1
        INSERT(id, j, k)
        id += 1
```